Solve a combinatorial problem under nested cardinality constraints
I am trying to solve the following optimization problem
\begin{align}
\underset{S_t \in \mathbb{S}}{\min} ~ \sum\limits_{S \subset S_t:|S| = M} f(S)
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{S} := \{S \subset \mathbb{N} : |S| = K\}$ represents the set of all possible assortments constrained by a cardinality limit $K$ and $\mathbb{N}:= \{1,\dots,N\}$ denotes the product universe. The objective is to minimize the sum of a function $f(S)$ over all subsets $S$ within the chosen assortment $S_t$, subject to the constraint that each subset $S$ has a fixed size $M$.
This problem exhibits a nested constraint structure, where the assortment $S_t$ is selected from the set of all possible assortments of size $K$, and the optimization is performed over subsets $S$ within $S_t$, each of size $M$.
One possible algorithm in my mind is to evaluate the function values for all subsets of size $M$ and rank these objective values to guide the reconstruction of $S_t$. By ranking the subsets according to their function values, we can iteratively build the assortment $S_t$ by selecting the subsets with the lowest function values, ensuring that the final assortment meets the cardinality constraint of size $K$. I would be very interested to know if there are any alternative algorithms.
Another idea I have is to use dynamic programming, though it could be challenging since the subsets may overlap.

How big are $K$, $N$, and $M$?  What can you tell us about $f$?

$M$ and $K$ are relatively small (e.g, M = 4, K = 30). $N$ can be very large (e.g., 1000). $f$ is a nonlinear function defined on subset $S$ but it is not very costly to evaluate.

Why are you imposing the constraint "s.t. $|S| = M$"? Because, it seems this condition should be imposed on the summation of the objective function, i.e. $\sum_{S \subset S_t : |S| = M} f(S)$. Is it right?

Furthermore, it seems that another way of conceiving the problem is by naming a set $\mathbb{S}M = { S \subset \mathbb{N}^{*}{\leqslant N} : |S| = M }$, and simply working with the program $\min_{S_M \subseteq \mathbb{S}M} \sum{s \in S_M} f(s)$ s.t. $|\bigcup(S_M)| = K$, is it right?

Yes. I have corrected the formulation and your conjecture is right!

Sorry for the delay. I have written a Constraint Programming formulation.

Status Quaestionis
Let $\mathbb{S}_M = \{ S \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}^{∗} :|S| = M \}$, as stated, we aim to solve $\min_{S_M \subseteq \mathbb{S}_M} \sum_{s \in S_M} f(s)$ s.t. $|\bigcup(S_M)| = K$.
Preliminar analysis
Note that, $\lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil \leqslant  |S_M|\leqslant C\binom{K}{M}$. We name $L$ as $C\binom{K}{M} - \lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil$.
Constraint Programming
Let $J = \{ 1, \dots, L \}$, and $I = \{ 1, \dots, M \}$.
We will first propose a Constraint Programming (CP) model, with an exponentional number of variables, precisely in the order of $O(L)$.

$s_i^j \in \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}$ be the $i$-th element of set $s^j$, $\forall i \in I, j \in J$ (note that, eventually, $s_i^j = 0$, in such cases we will interpret this set as empty);
$c^j \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall j \in J$ be $f(s^j)$; And
$v_k \in \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}^{*}$ be the $k$-th selected value, $\forall k \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ (remember that $|\bigcup(S_M)| = K$);

We will have the following CP model.
$\max \sum_{j \in J} c^j$
s.t.

$s^j_i \neq s^j_k$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \forall j \in J, i, k \in I : i \neq k$ (each set is composed of distinct elements, in the CP environment, this constraint is known as allDifferent, cf. here and here);
$s^j_i \neq 0 \implies \exists_{k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant K} (v_k = s^j_i)$, $\forall i \in I, j \in J$ (the used number must be placed accordingly into the "array" $v$);
$v_k \neq v_{k^{'}}$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \forall k, k^{'} : 1 \leqslant k, k^{'} \leqslant K \wedge k \neq k^{'}$ (allDifferent);
$s^j_i = 0 \implies s^j_k = 0$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \forall j \in J, i, k \in I : i \neq k$ (if one element of a set is zero, it means that it must be empty, i.e. all entries of $s^j$ must be zero);
$\nexists_{i \in I} (s^j_i = 0) \implies c^j = f(s^j)$, $\quad\forall j \in J$; And
$\exists_{i \in I} (s^j_i = 0)  \implies c^j = 0$, $\quad\quad\quad \forall j \in J$ (both, 5 and 6, guarantee that the cost $c$ will be updated accordingly).

CP Symmetry breaking

$\exists_{i \in I} (s^j_i = 0) \implies \exists_{i \in I} (s^{j + 1}_i = 0)$, $\quad\forall j \in J : j < L$ (If set $j$ is empty, then set $j + 1$ must be empty as well).

CP Complexities

Variables: $O(|J||I| + K) = O(LM + K) = O((C\binom{K}{M} - \lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil)M + K) = O(C\binom{K}{M} M)$;
Constraints: $O(|J||I|^2 + K^2) = O(L M^2 + K^2) = O((C\binom{K}{M} - \lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil) M^2 + K^2) =$ $O(C\binom{K}{M} M^2 - K (M - k))$.

Mixed Integer Non-Linear Programming
Let

$x_n^j \in \mathbb{B}$ be $1$ if set $j \in J$ contains element $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}$, and $0$ otherwise; And
$y_n \in \mathbb{B}$ be $1$ if set element $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}$ is used by some set, and $0$ otherwise.

Let $\mathcal{N} = \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}^{*}$.
We consider the following MINLP model.
$\max \sum_{j \in J} c^j$
s.t.

$\sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}} x_n^j = (1 - x_0^j) M$, $\forall j \in J$ (every set have exatcly $M$ elements;
$y_n \leqslant \sum_{j \in J} x^j_n$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\forall n \in \mathcal{N}$ (update the variables $y$);
$x^j_n \leqslant y_n$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\forall j \in J, n \in \mathcal{N}$ (if an element is used in some set, it must be counted in the variables $y$);
$\sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}} y_n = K$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad$ ($K$ elements must be used when uniting all the used sets $j$);
$1 \geqslant x_0^j + x_n^j$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \forall n \in \mathcal{N}, j \in J$ (if element $0$ is used in a set, it means that such set $j$ is empty);
$c^j \leqslant x_0^j f(x^j)$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\forall j \in J$ (guarantee that the cost $c$ will be updated accordingly).

MINLP Symmetry breaking

$x_0^j \leqslant x_0^{j + 1}$, $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\forall j \in J : j < L$ (if set $j$ is empty, then set $j + 1$ must be empty as well).

MINLP Complexities

Variables: $O(|J|N + K) = O(LN + K) = O((C\binom{K}{M} - \lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil)N + K)$;
Constraints: $O((C\binom{K}{M} - \lceil \frac{K}{M} \rceil)N + K)$.

Update 1: Description of the MINLP model.
Update 2: Thanks @RobPratt for the fixing.

I've tried to come up with a MILP model, but I couldn't make it without enumerating every $N$ choice, that is, $z^j_n = 1$ if set $j \in J$ contains element $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\leqslant N}^{*}$, and $0$ otherwise. And, I think that the $N$ you are working on should be quite large. Anyways, I can extend this thread to comprehend the MILP case, let me know case you are interested.

Thank you! Could you please elaborate on the MILP case?

Sorry for the delay, I've just added the corresponding MINLP model. Thinking carefully, I noticed that it may not end up as a MILP, since the function $f$ may be nonlinear.

PS.: maybe there is a way of modeling constraint 5 without adding more nonlinearity, however, I couldn't make it so far.

In your MINLP, constraints 2 and 3  enforce only that $|\cup S_M|\ge K$. You also need $x_n^j\le y_n$. Or you could impose the (weaker) aggregation $\sum_{j\in J} x_n^j\le |J|y_n$.

Thanks @RobPratt, let me know case you find another error.

PS. correction: maybe there is a way of modeling constraint 6 without adding more nonlinearity, however, I couldn't make it so far.

Also in the MINLP, constraint 4 (now 5 after your edit) is valid but already enforced by constraint 1 when $x_0^j\in{0,1}$.

Thanks. Yes, I was wondering about it, because, it seems that constraint (now as) 5, stands more as a strengthening cut for circumventing the big-$M$ stuff. However, I do not have any fractional example at hand right now.
